# How to set Eclipse PDT follow Zend Framework 2 coding convention?

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework2

I am learning Zend Framework 2. When I press `Ctrl + Shift + F` combine keys for auto format code, it show doesn't like Zend Framework 2 coding convention. 
Please show me **an easy way** to auto format code **follow Zend Framework coding convention** in **Eclipse 4.4 Luna PDT** (PHP Development Tool).

Answer (score 1):

I used to work with Eclipse and PDT a while. Then I switch to an other IDE. Anyway, in Eclipse you can edit how the autoformat will work. You can edit the Autoformat at **Window** -> **Preferences** and then under **PHP** -> **Code Style**. For me it worked well from the beginning with Zend Framework 2.

There you will also find the possibility to export / import settings. I just exported mine.
You can save following code as .xml and then import it at the same location you are able to edit the settings. Hope this may will help you.

Don't forget, first make a backup of yours, just to be sure. (I used Eclipse 4.2.2 & PDT 3.1.1)

**XML for Code Templates**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><templates><template autoinsert="true" context="php_gettercomment_context" deleted="false" description="Comment for getter methods" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.gettercomment" name="gettercomment">/**
 * @return the ${bare_field_name}
 */</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_settercomment_context" deleted="false" description="Comment for setter methods" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.settercomment" name="settercomment">/**
 * @param ${field_type} ${bare_field_name}
 */</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_constructorcomment_context" deleted="false" description="Comment for created constructors" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.constructorcomment" name="constructorcomment">/**
 * ${tags}
 */</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_filecomment_context" deleted="false" description="Comment for created PHP files" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.filecomment" name="filecomment">/**
 * 
 */
</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_typecomment_context" deleted="false" description="Comment for created types" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.typecomment" name="typecomment">/**
 * @author ${user}
 *
 * ${tags}
 */</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_fieldcomment_context" deleted="false" description="Comment for fields" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.fieldcomment" name="fieldcomment">/**
 * @var ${field_type}
 */</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_methodcomment_context" deleted="false" description="Comment for non-overriding methods" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.methodcomment" name="methodcomment">/**
 * ${tags}
 */</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_overridecomment_context" deleted="false" description="Comment for overriding methods" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.overridecomment" name="overridecomment">/* (non-PHPdoc)
 * ${see_to_overridden}
 */</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_delegatecomment_context" deleted="false" description="Comment for delegate methods" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.delegatecomment" name="delegatecomment">/**
 * ${tags}
 * ${see_to_target}
 */</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_newtype_context" deleted="false" description="Newly created files" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.newtype" name="newtype">${filecomment}
${package_declaration}

${typecomment}
${type_declaration}</template><template autoinsert="false" context="php_classbody_context" deleted="false" description="Code in new class type bodies" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.classbody" name="classbody">
</template><template autoinsert="false" context="php_interfacebody_context" deleted="false" description="Code in new interface type bodies" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.interfacebody" name="interfacebody">
</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_catchblock_context" deleted="false" description="Code in new catch blocks" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.catchblock" name="catchblock">// ${TODO} Auto-generated catch block
${exception_var}.printStackTrace();</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_methodbody_context" deleted="false" description="Code in created method stubs" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.methodbody" name="methodbody">// ${TODO} Auto-generated method stub
${body_statement}</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_constructorbody_context" deleted="false" description="Code in created constructor stubs" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.constructorbody" name="constructorbody">${body_statement}
// ${TODO} Auto-generated constructor stub</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_getterbody_context" deleted="false" description="Code in created getters" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.getterbody" name="getterbody">return ${field};</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_setterbody_context" deleted="false" description="Code in created setters" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.codetemplates.setterbody" name="setterbody">${field} = ${param};</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_new_file_context" deleted="false" description="Simple php file" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.author" name="New simple PHP file">&lt;?php
${cursor}</template><template autoinsert="true" context="php_new_file_context" deleted="false" description="html 4.01 frameset" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.html.frameset" name="New PHP file - HTML frameset">&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"&gt;
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
&lt;meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=${encoding}"&gt;
&lt;title&gt;Insert title here&lt;/title&gt;
&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;frameset&gt;
    &lt;frame&gt;
    &lt;frame&gt;
    &lt;noframes&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;This page uses frames. The current browser you are using does not support frames.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;?php
${cursor}
    ?&gt;
    &lt;/body&gt;
    &lt;/noframes&gt;
&lt;/frameset&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;</template></templates>
```

**Formatter settings**

The Settings from the menupoint **Formatters** (just below Code Templates) are set up like this in my Eclipse:

Tab Policy: Tabs

Indentation size: 1

Tab size: 4

Default indentatino for wrappen lines: 1

Default indentation for array initializers: 1

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework 2 coding standards are principally based on [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) with some minor additions. I'm not really sure about that additions but it should be minimal and you can try to find by reading all of [this](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Coding+Standards) and [this](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/coding.standard.html). Also there is a [meeting log exists from June 2012](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/2012-06-20+Meeting+Log) which contains a discussion about this subject.

I never understand why they prefer to introduce yet another new coding standard named "zend" instead of simply following and supporting the PSR-2 as is.

Basically, i think adjusting your IDE for PSR-2 will be enough.

Here is some resources:

- **[PHP CS Fixer by FriendsOfPhp](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer)** - The PHP Coding Standards Fixer tool fixes most issues in your code when you want to follow the PHP coding standards as defined in the PSR-1 and PSR-2 documents. (Check out this links for: [homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/blob/master/Formula/php-cs-fixer.rb), [sublime text](https://github.com/benmatselby/sublime-phpcs), [vim](https://github.com/stephpy/vim-php-cs-fixer), [netbeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/49042/php-cs-fixer))
- **[PSR-2 gist by netojoaobatista](https://gist.github.com/netojoaobatista/4337111)** - Code formatter for Zend Studio using the FIG-Standards PSR-2 Coding Style Guide. (As far as i know, zend studio has built-in support for PSR-2)
- **[Netbeans-psr by maniaplanet](https://maniaplanet.github.io/netbeans-psr/)** - A dedicated project for netbeans settings to comply to PHP's PSR 1 & 2 ([Github link](https://github.com/maniaplanet/netbeans-psr))
- **[PDT Extension Group](http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/)** - PDT extension group provides native semantic analysis plugin support for php-cs-fixer. ([Github link](https://github.com/pdt-eg/Core-Plugin))

There is no easy & magic way exists to format your code based on ZF2 standards by using a keyboard shortcut combination but yes, it is possible. Every IDE has different characteristics, settings, best-practices and approaches.

All you need is adjusting your IDE carefully for PSR-2 after reading some documentation. I strongly recommend to use [php-cs-fixer](http://cs.sensiolabs.org/).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Go TO 
Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Select from active profile (Zend).